# Can I display my own HTML in Liferay?

Tags: html, liferay, portlet

I am trying to display my own HTML file inside of a Liferay Portal.
Is this possible? If it is, how do I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Liferay is a CMS too, so what you need to learn is its [Web Content Management](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/using-liferay-web-content-management) system.

Answer (score 1):

How are you trying to display HTML file.?
Yes, your custom html files can be loaded in liferay portal.

Comment: How can I do this? I have an HTML file with javascript but I don't know how to make it part of a portlet

Comment: You create a portlet using the Plugins SDK and you add your HTML to a JSP file of that portlet (usually view.jsp).

Answer (score 1):

Download Eclipse Juno from [here](http://www.liferay.com/downloads/liferay-projects/liferay-ide) (already including the Liferay SDK). After that create new project in Eclipse FILE-->NEW-->Liferay Project. This will show you an additional windows to enter some details about your portlet. After you are done with this just follow [this link](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/anatomy-of-a-portlet).

Follow the tutorial and you will be ok. There they explain how to customize the look of the portlet. In the ".jsp" files you can just paste the html code and its going to work. Just dont forget to include the html tag library in your JSP file. Just paste: 
`<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>` on top of the document and you are done!

Hope that helped!

Good luck with your portal development!